# Sync useState and DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am having an issue. When I tried to update my trips array through the search input, I am having the previous state. I mean, if I search "a" nothing happens, if then I search "ab", I got trips filter by title "a". If then I search "abc" I got trips filter by title = "ab" and so on, I tried with useEffect, but when I print the trips value, I still get the previous one. I understand this is because useState is asynchronous, but how do I make React wait for the trips value?

The trips hook is defined in a parent component that render the Search component (the form to filter trips" and pass trips as props along with the setTrips function), and also render the Trips components that has trips as a props.

This is the parent Component where hooks are defined:

```
function MainContent() {
   const [trips, setTrips] = React.useState(tripList);

   return <main>
      <Search trips={tripList} tripsHook={setTrips} />
      <Trips trips={trips} />
   </main>
}
```

`tripList` is a variable that has the initial list.

Here is where I try to update the trip's state (The Search Component):

```
function Search({ trips, tripsHook }: { trips: typeof tripList, tripsHook: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<typeof tripList>> }) {
   const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = React.useState("");
   const [durationSelection, setDurationSelection] = React.useState("");
   const [lvlSelection, setLvlSelection] = React.useState("");

   return <>
         <form className="trips-filter__form" autoComplete="off" onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
            <label>
               <input value={searchInput} onChange={(e) => {
                  handleChange(e.target.value, setSearchInput);
               }} />
            </label>
            <label>
               <select value={lvlSelection} onChange={(e) => {
                  handleChange(e.target.value, setLvlSelection);
               }}>
                  <option value="">level</option>
                  <option value="easy">easy</option>
                  <option value="moderate">moderate</option>
                  <option value="difficult">difficult</option>
               </select>
            </label>
         </form>
   </>

   function handleChange<T>(value: string, hookFunc: Function) {
      hookFunc(value);
      tripsHook(searchTrips());
   }

   function searchTrips(): typeof trips {
      let re: RegExp;
      let newTrips: typeof trips = trips.slice();
      if (searchInput) {
         re = new RegExp(`${searchInput}`, "i");
         newTrips = newTrips.filter(trip => re.test(trip.title));
      }
      if (lvlSelection) {
         re = new RegExp(`${lvlSelection}`, "i");
         newTrips = newTrips.filter(trip => re.test(trip.level));
      }
      return newTrips;
   }
}
```

This is the useEffect I tried:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log(trips);
}, [trips]);

function MainContent() {
  const [trips, setTrips] = React.useState(tripList);
  //Same as above
}
```

How can I make React wait for trips to render the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer I have is that you have to pass e.target.value to your tripsHook. It looks like you need to do some filtering of e.target.value before it gets there but essentially the issue is that you are using state to update state when you want to use the value from your search directly.

I would also do all of the filtering/state handling of the trips in the MainContent component

```
const MainContent = () => {
  const [trips, setTrips] = React.useState(tripList);

  function searchTrips(value) { // declare function to handle filtering and state changes of the trips returned from the search
    let newTrips = trips.filter(trip => {
      // do some filtering with the value from the search
    });
    setTrips(newTrips);
  }

  return (
    <main>
      <Search trips={tripList} searchTrips={searchTrips} />
      <Trips trips={trips} />
    </main>
  )
}

const Search = ({ trips, searchTrips }) => {

  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = React.useState("");
  function handleChange (e) {
    setSearchInput(e.target.value);
    searchTrips(e.target.value);
  }
  return (
    <form>
      <input value={searchInput} 
      onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
    </form>
  )
}
```

It would end up looking like the above example but with all of your filtering in the Main Component.

The key is using the value directly from the search input to change state on that render. There are many ways you could change your code to do so but I think this answer should get you to where you need to go. Let me know if you continue to have issues.

Comment: Ok, i think i understand you (maybe lol), but when you say i used states to update states, do you mean because in the searchTrips function i used the states variables of searchInput, durationSelection etc? Do you mind to explain that part in more detail? i mean, i think that i updated the "tripHook" with searchTrips function that just return a new list of trips (i changed the code, that part is suppose to be something like trips.slice()).

Comment: State setting in React is asynchronous, and happens after the execution of your code. If you need to use the value of some state that you're updating, you'll need to pass that value to the function that needs to use it manually, like Luke said. This is done so they can batch state updates together for more efficient renders. In this case, your input's state and your trips state would be set at the same time after your code blocks are executed. See the docs here for more info: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous